# How do I watch changes to an object? this.$set seems to capture only property update

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have this object of arrays that I'm tryin to watch every update of.

```
myData = {
    "299":[527],
    "376":[630,629]
}
```

I read this [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) on watching an object which instructed to use either `this.$set(object, propertyName, value)` or `Object.assign({}, this.object, dataToBeAppended)` to watch an object. I used `this.$set`.

```
export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      myData: {},
    };
  },
  watch: {
    myData(newVal) {
      console.log(`localStorage`);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onFoldChange(propertyName) {
      const newArr = [...]
      this.$set(this.myData, propertyName, newArr);
    },
  }
}
```

Unlike what I expected, vue captures changes on property only. Changes in value to an existing property are not being watched. For example, if a property `"299"` was newly added, it will print `localStorage`.  When the value of a property `"299"` is updated from `[527]` to something else, nothing is fired. When I print `myData`, I see every value updated correctly. It is just that watch isn't capturing the changes.

The documentation also described we can watch an array using `this.$set(this.myData, indexOfItem, newValue)` so I also tried array version of the above code, like this.

```
this.$set(this.myData[propertyName], index, newValueToAdd);
```

This time it doesn't listen at all. Not even the first entry.

Is there any better way to solve this issue? How do others watch an object? Is the complication coming from the type of values (array) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `myData` watcher observes only an object. Object contains pointers to arrays as in JS Objects & Arrays are passed by reference not by copy. That's why it can detect only changes in keys and with simple values. If you want to observe it deeper - I mean also those subarrays (or subobjects) - just use deep watch.

```
watch: {
  myData: {
    deep: true,
    handler (newVal) {
      console.log(`localStorage`);
    }
  }
}
```

Another possible solution could be to use some Array.prototype operation to modify an array if it already exists. E.g:

```
methods: {
    onFoldChange(propertyName) {
      if (propertyName in this.myData && Array.isArray(this.myData[propertyName])) {
           this.myData[properyName].push(162) // Some random value
      } else {
           const newArr = [...]
           this.$set(this.myData, propertyName, newArr);
      }
    },
  }
```